# Section outlines in beamer Rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

How can I have the outline of a beamer presentation appear before each section in Rmarkdown, like [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27378/show-plan-before-each-section-except-the-first-one) for regular beamer?

Comment: The question or the answer?

Comment: How can we use Rmarkdown to produce outline slides that change as the sections progress

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in `header.tex`:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}<beamer>
 \frametitle{Plan}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection]
 \end{frame}
}
```

And compile with:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---
```